# How to set Many to Many field blank=True on both sides in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django rest and today encounted a little trouble:
Let's say we have two models:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tag_text = models.CharField(name='tag', max_length=30)
```

and

```
class Entries(models.Model):
    entry_header = models.CharField(name='header', max_length=30)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    entry_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    entry_tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, related_name='entries', blank=True)
```

I can set *blank* property for Entries model, but have difficulty with doing the same to Tags.
This way when I'm trying something like

```
http --json POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/tags/ tag_text="tag with no entry"
```

it returns me

```
"entries": [ This field is required ]
```

Is there any way I can creatre Tags object with blank "entries" field in this case?

Thank you in advance!

---

...and please note that

```
http --json POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/entries/ header="entry with no tags"
```

gives desired response

serializers from rest_framework would be quite simple in this case as well:

```
class EntriesSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entries
        fields = ('url', 'header', 'entry_text', 'pub_date', 'entry_tags')

class TagsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ('url', 'tag', 'entries')
```

and here are our views (viewsets from rest_framework to make it quick):

```
class EntriesView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Entries.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntriesSerializer

class TagsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tags.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagsSerializer
```

All go throught default router (from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter):

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'entries', views.EntriesView)
router.register(r'tags', views.TagsView)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Could you set `tag_text = models.CharField(name='tag', max_length=30)` to `tag_text = models.CharField(name='tag', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)`?

Or you may need to add `null=True` on the ManyToManyField.

Comment: @Caleb_Allen I tried to add null=True to m2m field even against documentation notes about null property effect... and it didn't work unfortunately...

Comment: Did you run migrations on your models? Might have an effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually problem appeared to be in Serializer, not in Model itself.
field property **required=False** should be used to emphasize that field is not mandatory during object creation if it wasn't specified during model description (and this way cannot be properly serialized).

```
class TagsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
entries = EntriesSerializer(many=True, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Tags
    fields = ('url', 'tag', 'entries')
```

Thanks to everyone responded to guide me in a right direction!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from testapp.models import Tags, Entries
>>> t = Tags.objects.create(tag = 'TAG')
>>> t
<Tags: Tags object>
```

It works for me, is not the model, is the Form, or the validator you are using

Comment: as far as I know from documentation: null has no effect since there is no way to require a relationship at the database level

Comment: You are right, it works. Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: I'm experiencing problems particularly with http POST so far. As you noticed there is no problem in creating such objects from the shell, this way it is not something impossible to make.

Comment: Can u post the view handling this POST?

Comment: From: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer
"Tip: Properly matching together hyperlinked representations and your URL conf can sometimes be a bit fiddly. Printing the repr of a HyperlinkedModelSerializer instance is a particularly useful way to inspect exactly which view names and lookup fields the relationships are expected to map too."

<I'm not sure about this but, can you set  the fields of TagsSerializer to fields = ('url', 'tag') And add extra extra_kwargs?

Comment: looks little tricky, but you are right, problem is not in a field but in request handlers

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `entries` read_only in your `TagsSerializer`.

You can do like:

```
class TagsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    entries = EntriesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ('url', 'tag', 'entries')
```

Comment: good idea! it allows object creation, but logically this field would not be really read_only in a real situation.